# Exchange Web Services (EWS) - How to identify if meeting participant is mail group or individual attendee

Tags: exchangewebservices

I am using EWS (Exchange Web Services) to do various operations with outlook meeting item. One of the requirement is to fetch created meeting and **identify if particular participant is mail group email address or individual attendee's email address.**

I could get meeting item using FindItem / GetItem however, not sure about how exactly participant's type can be checked.

Can you please suggest if any such option available with EWS ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You will need a GetItem to see the attendees of a Meeting as FindItem won't return that information. Once you have the recipients you can check the MailboxType property https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.mailboxtype?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=exchange-ews-api . If that doesn't work then try the FindPeople operation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/findpeople-operation. If you using Office365 then doing a Graph lookup is probably a better and eaiser option to find that information.

Comment: thanks! seems should work. will try and confirm.